# Awesome nested set: Performance improvement for self_and_descendants

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, rubygems

Recently started working on a existing project which heavily relies on [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem and used one of it's method's `self_and_descendants` refer [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet)

This method is too heavy in terms of pulling all the children and triggers many queries.  I have indexing in place but looking for a alternative to come out of this performance issue.

Sample Sqls that are triggered

```
q = Group.first
q.self_and_descendants
```

The above code triggers below queries, there are many more only some are pasted

```
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2231
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2233
  Group::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2239
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2240
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2241
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2242
  Group::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `group_translations`.* FROM `group_translations` WHERE `group_translations`.`group_id` = 2252
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time and no replies. :) I landed up doing this.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_nested_set

 def self_and_descendants_hashed
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE lft >= #{self.lft} AND rgt <= #{self.rgt} order by lft")
  end
end
```